# Problem with function to determine the winner of multiple rounds in a dice game

Tags: ruby, dice

We have an assignment to determine the ultimately winner in a dice game. Here's the complete rules:

You will be pitted against two other computer players in this game. There are three rounds. At the beginning of each round a player rolls two dice. The total of your dice roll for that round is added to your points. Your points always start at zero. Each consecutive round the points are added to the total. At the end of the third round, whoever has the most points wins the game.

REQUIREMENTS
————————
Each player has two dice
The player rolls each die once per round
Display each players score at the end of each round
Display the leader of the round at the end of each round
Prompt the user to roll to begin the next around
After three rounds the game is over
The players score persists until the end of the game
Once the game ends, a winner is declared
Once a winner is declared you have the option to restart or quit

I've gotten everything to work, except how to determine the ultimate winner of the game. I've tried making a new method called "gameWinner", using if/elsif statements, grabbing the total scores from each round and adding each up respectively. However, the program breaks once it reaches that. I can't think of how else to solve this problems, but nothing I type seems to function right.

```
def welcome
    puts ""
    puts "Let's roll some die! You will be competing against 2 computers in 3 rounds, each player having 2 die."
    puts "Please enter your name and press 'Enter'"
    puts ""
    @userName = gets.chomp
    puts ("Welcome, " + @userName + ". Let's roll those die!")
    puts ""
end

def round(round)
    result_1 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    result_2 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    total_1 = result_1 + result_2

    result_3 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    result_4 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    total_2 = result_3 + result_4

    result_5 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    result_6 = Random.new.rand(1..6)
    total_3 = result_5 + result_6

    winner = [total_1, total_2, total_3].max
    players = {total_1 => @userName, total_2 => "Computer 1", total_3 => "Computer 2"}.max

    puts "Round #{round}"
    puts "#{@userName}, your die are a #{result_1} and a #{result_2}, totaling #{total_1}"
    puts "Computer 1's die are a #{result_3} and a #{result_4}, totaling #{total_2}"
    puts "Computer 2's die are a #{result_5} and a #{result_6}, totaling #{total_3}"
    puts "Round #{round} highest score is: #{winner}"
        if total_1> total_2 && total_3
            puts "#{@userName} is the winner!"
        elsif total_2 > total_1 && total_3
            puts "Computer 1 is the winner!"
        elsif total_3 > total_1 && total_2
            puts "Computer 2 is the winner!"
        else
            puts "It was a tie, there are no winners."
        end
    puts ""  
end

def gameWinner(rounds)
    if total_1> total_2 && total_3
        roundWinner1 = 1
    elsif total_2 > total_1 && total_3
        roundWinner2 = 1
    else total_3 > total_1 && total_2
        roundWinner3 = 1
    end

    gameSummary1 = roundWinner1 + roundWinner1 + roundWinner1
    gameSummary2 = roundWinner2 + roundWinner2 + roundWinner2
    gameSummary3 = roundWinner3 + roundWinner3 + roundWinner3
    winnerOA = [gameSummary1, gameSummary2, gameSummary3].max

    puts "The winner of the game is #{winnerOA}"
end

def playAgain
    puts "Would you like to start over? (Y/N)\n"
    answer = gets.chomp.upcase
    if answer == "Y"
        play
    elsif answer == "N"
        puts "Thank you for playing.\n"
    else
        playAgain
    end    
  end

def play
    welcome
    round(1)
    round_1 = round(1)   
    round(2)
    round(3)
    gameWinner    
    playAgain
end

play
```

I've expected the program to report the overall winner, but I'm just blanking on how to grab it.

Here is the error thrown by the `gameWinner` function:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 2: from rollEm2.rb:83:in ' 1: from rollEm2.rb:79:in play' rollEm2.rb:44:in `gameWinner': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help you, we need to see your `gameWinner` function and know what you mean by "the program breaks". What is the error thrown? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I've edited the gameWinner back in. I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from rollEm2.rb:83:in `<main>'
        1: from rollEm2.rb:79:in `play'
rollEm2.rb:44:in `gameWinner': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: the error is telling you that `gameWinner` is being called without required arguments. see line 79

Comment: Forgive me for nitpicking, but the word "die" is singular, and "dice" is plural.  For example:  "I have one die; she has two dice."  (This is a common error among native English speakers.)  If you need help remembering which word is plural, just realize that many English plural nouns end in an "s" sound, and the plural word "dice" is no exception here.

Comment: Also in in `gameWinner(rounds)`: 1. the variables `total_1`, `total_2` and `total_3` are not defined (maybe add `@` at the beginning of the name to render it "global"). 2. Only one variable takes a value: `roundWinner1`, `roundWinner2`, `roundWinner3` due to the `if` statement, so initialise them `roundWinner1, roundWinner2, roundWinner3 = 0, 0, 0`

Comment: Ahhh! the global @ -- new to me, and I can't seem to remember that - thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The method `gameWinner` is being called without arguments but looks like the argument expected is not used in your method. So try to remove it from the definition:

```
def gameWinner
  #... your method code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more Ruby-like way to think of the problem, using a `Player` class. Note that the numbers of players and rounds are not fixed. I have omitted prompts to ask players to roll the dice. If the first two lines of the definition of the class are head-scratchers, not to worry--see the explanation at the end of the answer.

```
class Player
  @players = []
  singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :players)

  attr_reader :name, :cum_score

  def initialize(name)
     @name = name
     @cum_score = 0
     self.class.players << self
  end

  def blow_on_dice
    # Come to papa!
  end

  def throw
    score = rand(1..6) + rand(1..6) 
    @cum_score += score
    score
  end
end
```

```
def show_winners(scores)
  max_score = scores.values.max
  winners = scores.select { |_,v| v == max_score }.keys
  if winners.size == 1
    puts "Winner with a score of #{max_score} is #{winners.first}"
  else
    print "Winners of round with a score of #{max_score} are "
    winners.each_with_index do |name,i|
      print name
      print case i
            when winners.size-1 then ''
            when winners.size-2 then ' and '
            else                ', '
            end
    end
    puts
  end
end
```

```
Player.new('Cary')
  #=> #<Player:0x000059a79738b768 @name="Cary", @cum_score=0> 
Player.new('Hal')
  #=> #<Player:0x000059a7973d7690 @name="Hal", @cum_score=0> 
Player.new('Deep Thought')
  #=> #<Player:0x000059a79756f318 @name="Deep Thought", @cum_score
nbr_rounds = 3
```

```
players = Player.players
  #=> [#<Player:0x000059a79738b768 @name="Cary", @cum_score=0>,
  #    #<Player:0x000059a7973d7690 @name="Hal", @cum_score=0>,
  #    #<Player:0x000059a79756f318 @name="Deep Thought", @cum_score=0>] 

(1..nbr_rounds).each do |round|
  puts "\nResults for round #{round}"
  scores = players.each_with_object({}) do |p,h|
    p.blow_on_dice
    score = p.throw
    puts "#{p.name} throws #{score}"
    h[p.name] = score
  end
  show_winners(scores)
end
```

```
Results for round 1
Cary throws 8
Hal throws 9
Deep Thought throws 9
Winners of round with a score of 9 are Hal and Deep Thought
```

```
Results for round 2
Cary throws 7
Hal throws 9
Deep Thought throws 9
Winners of round with a score of 9 are Hal and Deep Thought
```

```
Results for round 3
Cary throws 7
Hal throws 11
Deep Thought throws 6
Winner with a score of 11 is Hal
```

```
puts "\nResults for all rounds"
scores = players.each_with_object({}) do |p,h|
  h[p.name] = p.cum_score
  puts "#{p.name} had a total score of #{p.cum_score}"
end
```

```
Results for all rounds
Cary had a total score of 22
Hal had a total score of 29
Deep Thought had a total score of 24
```

```
show_winners(scores)
```

```
Winner with a score of 29 is Hal
```

If the line

```
puts "scores = #{scores}"
```

is inserted before the first line in `show_winners`, the following is displayed for the three each-round calculations:

```
scores = {"Cary"=>7, "Hal"=>5, "Deep Thought"=>7}
scores = {"Cary"=>4, "Hal"=>7, "Deep Thought"=>3}
scores = {"Cary"=>10, "Hal"=>11, "Deep Thought"=>8}
```

For the totals calculation the following is displayed:

```
scores = {"Cary"=>21, "Hal"=>23, "Deep Thought"=>18}
```

Note that `@players` is an instance_variable for the class (as opposed to instances of the class). The line `singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :players)` creates a getter for that variable, allowing us to write `Player.players` to obtain an array of the instances of `Players` that have been created. One of several alternatives to that line is the following:

```
class << self
  attr_reader :players
end
```

Alternatively, the collection of instances of `Players` that have been created would be maintained outside the class, but that is prone to error (if, for example, a player is later added):

```
players = [Player.new('Cary'), Player.new('Hal'), Player.new('Deep Thought')]
```

Were that done the class definition would be simplified to the following.

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name, :cum_score

  def initialize(name)
     @name = name
     @cum_score = 0
  end

  def throw
    ...
  end
end
```

This design, however, prone to error (if, for example, a player were later added) and `players` were not updated.